# What particular word is used for this doll?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

A doll is created which looks like a human and is kept near or among crops in the farm to keep animals like deer away.

I don't know what it is called in English.

[image: scarecrows]

Comment: If it is a scarecrow, it would be more appropriate to use the word "doll" than "statue", as "statue" seems to imply a esthetic concern on the making of it

Comment: it could be a statue though, if it has a symbolic/spiritual meaning, some cultures make use of figures like this

Comment: An *inukshuk* is a pile of stones made in a human shape. It serves various functions, but one is to herd caribou. It's not quite what you're asking, but it *is* more like a statue than a scarecrow is. See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inukshuk

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This human-like object is called [**scarecrow**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarecrow).

Comment: From your link: "A scarecrow is, essentially, a decoy. Traditionally, it is a human figure (or mannequin) dressed in old clothes and placed in fields by farmers *to discourage birds such as crows or sparrows* from disturbing and feeding on recently cast seed and growing crops." (my emphasis). The OP mentioned scaring deer away, which I doubt a scarecrow would do.

Comment: It seems that decoy is a more broad term, but "scarecrow" isn't necessarily wrong if in usage this term turned out to be "a device to protect fields from damage of animals". As far as I'm concerned, some objects end up being called "scarecrow" even thought they don't resemble human figures. Just some thoughts.